# Hubot And Django Development Server

Tags: django, coffeescript, hubot

I am trying to make a get request using coffeeScript, but it is not even making a request to my URL:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.respond /foo (.*) bar (.*) foobar (.*) /i, (msg) ->
    foo = msg.match[1]
    bar = msg.match[2]
    foobar = msg.match[3]
    robot.http("http://localhost:8000/a/")
      .query({
        'foo': foo
        'bar': bar
        'foobar': foobar
      })
      .get() (err, res, body) ->
        json = JSON.parse(body)
        msg.send(json)
```

When i make the same request with my browser it works:

```
http://localhost:8000/a/?foo=1&bar=2&foobar=3
```

I am trying to run hubot as

```
hubot 1 bar 2 foobar 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Your CoffeeScript syntax is a bit off. Your structure in your `get` call is like this:

```
f() x
```

when you want it to be like this:

```
f x
```

This part:

```
.get() (err, res, body) ->
    json = JSON.parse(body)
    msg.send(json)
```

will call `get` with no arguments and then call whatever `get` returns as a function with `(err, res, body) -> ...` as an argument. Presumably you want to pass the callback to `get` as an argument:

```
.get (err, res, body) ->
    json = JSON.parse(body)
    msg.send(json)
```

Comment: thanks, but it is still not hitting my localhost url

Comment: Are you sure it is even matching your regex and getting into your handler?

Comment: It works in browser but not from here, i am sure there is something missing in my hubot script only.

Comment: Is your callback getting called at all?

Comment: Does your regent match what you're trying to match?